# Notifications are being identified as the wrong application

Tags: icons, notifications

This has happened with a few applications but for example, I have have Slack installed but when I get a notification, it shows up as being from RubyMine.

[image]

I'm curious why these aren't being properly identified by the OS. Is it merely an issue with the .desktop files? For reference:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Slack
Comment=Slack Desktop
GenericName=Slack Client for Linux
Exec=/usr/bin/slack --disable-gpu %U
Icon=/usr/share/pixmaps/slack.png
Type=Application
StartupNotify=true
Categories=GNOME;GTK;Network;InstantMessaging;
MimeType=x-scheme-handler/slack;

[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Name=RubyMine
Icon=/home/my_user/apps/RubyMine-2016.2.3/bin/RMlogo.svg
Exec="/home/my_user/apps/RubyMine-2016.2.3/bin/rubymine.sh" %f
Comment=The Drive to Develop
Categories=Development;IDE;
Terminal=false
StartupWMClass=jetbrains-rubymine
```

Comment: That's strange. It seems sporadic. I wonder if imgur is having server troubles.

Comment: I also have a somewhat similar issue where the notification window saying my machine will suspend (when battery is low) has the dropbox icon on it (but not the name)

Comment: I'm also having this issue with Radio Tray Lite song change is being reported as a Whatever (very nice Evernote client) notification.
Funny thing, neither apps are registered with Switchboard Plug Notifications so there is nothing for me to change.

Comment: I'm having the same issue where Slack notifications are shown as PHPStorm notifications.

Comment: I think the issue happens with any app that is based on Electron; Slack, Insomnia, etc

Comment: Please log a bug here https://bugs.launchpad.net/gala/+bug/1622808